# Jquery mobile ending current (persisting) touch events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-mobile

I need to make sure that when `pageRemove` event launches. If the user currently touches the screen, the touch will be ended.

Since I do not know if and what element is touched in order to trigger a `touchend` event on it, I tried::

```
 $('*').trigger('touchend');
```

Yet it dosn't really seem to do anything, and the touch event persists to the next page.

Is there a way to make sure all current touch (usually long touches) are ended on the `pageRemove` event?

Comment: This code works for me:
   `$('*').on('touchend', function(){console.log('test')});`

Comment: Sorry if I miss anything, but doesn't the code sample you written sets the touchend itself as the event? I want to trigger the touchend event when the pageremove event launches automatically by jQuery mobile, so currently happening touch events will end...

Comment: Ok, sorry I misunderstood. I think a better approach is to try to control the touchevent better. If you know which element they touch you can call `.trigger('touchevent')` on that. The -trigger-event appears to work on specific elements but not if you write `$('*')`

Comment: Sounds possible, The thing is i'm not sure what element they will click. maybe some event tracking into variables. i'll try that and will update how it goes. Meanwhile, thanks for the help.